ROS2 package installation error
It seems like there's an issue with the ROS 2 repository for Ubuntu Mantic, as indicated by the "404 Not Found" error.
How do I fix this?
Err:4 http://packages.ros.org/ros2/ubuntu mantic Release                       
   404  Not Found 
                                       
E: The repository 'http://packages.ros.org/ros2/ubuntu mantic Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.


I think ROS only supports ubuntu LTS releases. Mantic is not one of them, is it?

You cannot install ROS in Ubuntu (23.10) and not LTS in the form of a binary package.
If necessary, you can install it through the source installation, but this will require more effort.
If you don't have to use magic, it is recommended to use 20.04 or 22.04.
I will attach a link related to this.
https://docs.ros.org/en/humble/Installation/Ubuntu-Install-Debians.html
https://docs.ros.org/en/humble/Installation/Alternatives/Ubuntu-Development-Setup.html
